# Data not loading on pageload with postback

Tags: c#

I am having a problem. Data is not loading once the page loads. I have to choose an item on the dropdown list for it to load. I need it to load even before I choose any item on the drop down list.

This is my code behind.

```
 protected void ddlPeriodStamp_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string selectedGroup = string.Empty;
    DropDownList ddlItemGroup = (DropDownList)sender;

    if (ddlItemGroup.SelectedValue != null)

        TreatmentGroup = ddlItemGroup.SelectedValue;
        ApplyGridFilter(ddlItemGroup.SelectedValue);


}

protected void ApplyGridFilter(string TreatmentGroup)
{
    string selectedGroup = string.Empty;
    DBDataSource1.State.BusinessObject.DataPump.FormFilters.Clear();
    DBDataSource1.State.BusinessObject.DataPump.FormFilters.Add("TreatmentGroup", TreatmentGroup);
    DBDataSource1.State.BusinessObject.Fill(null);
    MedicalSchemeDetailGrid.DataBind();
}
protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

    if (!this.IsPostBack)
            ApplyGridFilter(string.Empty);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `ApplyGridFilter(string.Empty);` while `ispostBack` is false and call `ApplyGridFilter(ddlItemGroup.SelectedValue);` while `ispostBack` is true

```
protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 {

   if (this.IsPostBack)
   {
     ApplyGridFilter(ddlItemGroup.SelectedValue);// it will hit on first time page load 
   }
   else
   {
     ApplyGridFilter(string.Empty);// it will hit while you change the dropdown items, But you should set true for **IsAutoPostBack** property on dropsownlist.    
   }
 }
```

Comment: still not working..i have set the autopostback to true

Answer (score 0):

You need to fill your data in Page_Load event not in Page_LoadComplete event. According to MSDN:

> The LoadComplete event occurs after all postback data and view-state
>   data is loaded into the page and after the OnLoad method has been
>   called for all controls on the page.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
        ApplyGridFilter(string.Empty);
}
```

Comment: i have added it to the pageload event but still no data is loading on the page load

Comment: After writing code in Page_Load, have you checked by putting break point, that ApplyGridFilter is called? and if its called, did you check that data is returned from DB?

Comment: it is not being called